# Rails daterange selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I've made a date-range form in my view to allow a user to input a date range and show their reports from within that specific range.  It starts out by filling in the `test_field_tags` in the view with the `.first.created_at` and `.last.created_at` values for the reports.  Now I'm trying to wire the controller correctly so the user can designate a date range, but it's not working for me.  Appreciate the help...

**index.html.erb**

```html
<%= form_tag({:action => "index"}, {:class => "form-inline"}) do %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= text_field_tag(:start_date, @reports.first.created_at, class: "form-control", name: "startdate") %>
    <p class="text-center">to</span>
    <%= text_field_tag(:end_date, @reports.last.created_at, class: "form-control", name: "enddate") %>
  </div>

  <%= submit_tag "Update", class: "update-button" %>
<% end %>
```

**reports_controller.rb**

```html
def index
  @company = current_user.company

  @locations = if @company
    current_user.company_locations.order(:name)
  else
    []
  end

  @reports = if @company
    @company.reports.where(created_at: params[:start_date]..params[:end_date]).order("created_at DESC").paginate(page: params[:page], :per_page => 30)
  else
    []
  end
  render 'reports/index.html.erb'
end

private
  def report_params
    params.permit(:start_date, :end_date)
  end
```

The issue that I'm running into now is that my placeholder value for the `text_field_tag` is not being inserted since my statement in the controller is relying on the `params[:start_date]` and `params[:end_date]` values.

What would be the best way to go about doing what I'm trying to accomplish...which is to pre-fill in the whole range that I have in the DB, but then allow the user to specify their own range and reload the page to yield those results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following edits:

(Note: the start and end dates will also feature a time component ; if you're only interested in dates, change those to `@reports.first.created_at.to_date.to_s` and `@reports.last.created_at.to_date.to_s`. However, it would be even cleaner to use the Rails `I18n` library).

```html
<%= form_tag({:action => "index"}, {:class => "form-inline"}) do %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= text_field_tag(:start_date, ((@reports.nil? || @reports.empty?) ? '' : @reports.first.created_at.to_s), class: "form-control", name: "startdate") %>
    <p class="text-center">to</span>
    <%= text_field_tag(:end_date, ((@reports.nil? || @reports.empty?) ? '' : @reports.last.created_at.to_s), class: "form-control", name: "enddate") %>
  </div>

  <%= submit_tag "Update", class: "update-button" %>
<% end %>
```

In your controller, you need to properly populate the `@reports` variable when the form is loaded (GET action), then update the same variable when the form is submitted (POST action):

(Note: do not forget the parentheses when defining your date range)

```html
def index
  @company = current_user.company
  unless @company.nil? || @company.reports.empty?
    if request.post?
      @reports = @company.reports.where(created_at: (params[:start_date]..params[:end_date])).order(created_at: :desc).paginate(page: params[:page], :per_page => 30)
    else
      @reports = @company.reports.order(created_at: :desc).paginate(page: params[:page], :per_page => 30)
    end
  end
  render 'reports/index.html.erb'
end
```

Edit: for routing purposes, your /config/routes.rb should include the following:

```
get 'reports/index' => "reports#index", as: :reports_index
post 'reports/index' => "reports#index"
```

Then you can edit the form tag declaration to the following:

```
<%= form_tag reports_index_path, method: :post, class: "form-inline" do %>
```

And just remove the `render` line from the `index` action in the controller. Finally, make sure your controller name is consistent with your views subdirectory name. If `index.html.erb` is located within `views/reports`, then your controller name should be `ReportsController` and the controller file `reports_controller.rb`. If it's singular, amend my answers accordingly.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.  I changed the code around as you suggested, but for some reason I'm redirected back to `root_path` and it seems to run the `ReportController#create` method.  What would cause this since my `form_tag` action is pointing to `index` ?

Comment: I edited my answer to include a basic routing configuration. Be mindful of the name(s) of your files and classes, however. I based my answers on the assumption that you have a ReportsController controller and views are located in app/views/reports.

Comment: I think that's my problem.  The original developer used `apipie` which put practically every controller under a `v1` directory.  Is there a way to scope those into the route without having to make another `Reports` Controller?

Comment: Hard to say without a global overview of the project structure, and that would be beyond the scope of your original question.

Comment: I think you're right.  I made the changes and I can click the update button now and it loads the right page.  I just ended up making another `Reports` controller that resides in the main controller directory and moved most of my code there.  Still haven't gotten the daterange update portion to work, but this is a good start for me.  thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. And good luck, I know from experience taking over another dev's project can be a real headache... if you run into other issues, I'll be glad to help if I can.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92091/discussion-between-godzilla74-and-jaxx).